# Linking buttons to pages using android(Eclipse) - can't get it to work

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development, and to this site!
I have done a few tutorials etc and am working on a project at the moment, and had a good look through other answers to similar questions, but haven't been able to find quite what i'm looking for (but loads of good suggestions!)

I am trying to get buttons on my main screen linking to individual pages. I am using my phone instead of an emulator, but every time i click on a button, the app dies... can you help me?

This is my main Screen code for button1:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Declaring and defining the buttons used
    Button student1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 // Setting the onClickListener for button1
    student1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //calling the page1 function
            page1(view);
        }
    });
```

This is the page1 function:

```
public void page1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is the code for the Page1 class file:

```
public class Page1 extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_1);
}

}
```

This is the code for the layout file: (page_1.xml)

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="shannon.white.finalyear.DisplayMessageActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

If you need anything else, let me know

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should take a look at your crash log to find out why your app dies. Or you can post it here so others can better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your coding looks to be correct.

The next thing to check would be to look inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to ensure you have added the activity to it so the android OS knows it exists. You add it like so:

```
<activity android:name="Page1" />
```

If your activity resides in a different package then the one declared inside the manifest file, then you need to specify the full package inside the "name" like so:

```
<activity android:name="some.other.package.name.Page1" />
```

Thats about all i can say from the provided code. If you are simply starting another activity which is `Page1.class` then your code looks correct and you might be missing the manifest declaration as i stated above.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I had the activity in the manifest file, but changing the name to include the package name worked! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this following code

```
// Declaring and defining the buttons used
    Button student1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 // Setting the onClickListener for button1
    student1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
```

underneath your page1 function so your code looks like this:

```
public void page1(View view) {

    Button student1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // Declaring and defining the buttons used
    student1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Setting the onClickListener for button1

    @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(intent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Page1.class);
      }
    }
}
```

and your onCreate look like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    page1(view); // NOTE I'm now declaring it on the onCreate instead of onClick
}
```

If that doesn't help, well your code still looks cleaner. Could just be my OCD though...

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/) is a very good tutorial by Mkyong on how to achieve what you are trying to do. If no other answers help, restarting using this tutorial will likely help you succeed. On multiple occasions I've tested his code and its worked.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your answer! It didn't work, but now my code looks a lot better, and the tutorial you linked me is fantastic! thanks :D